# accessing variables that is declared inside initComponent sencha

Tags: android, iphone, model-view-controller, extjs

I need to render a template in sencha in mvc pattern , so on InitComponent i have declared some variable but i am unable to acess those variable outside init function . I did following try

```
Ext.define('casta.view.Intro', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    //alias: 'widget.currentDate', //this makes it xtype 'currentDate'
    //store: 'CurrentDateStore',


    initComponent: function(){
        this.planetEarth = { name: "Earth", mass: 1.00 };

        this.tpl = new Ext.Template(['<tpl for".">', '<p> {name} </p>', '</tpl>'].join(''));
        this.tpl.compile();
        this.callParent(arguments);

    },
    html:this.tpl.apply(this.planetEarth)
});
```

ERROR

```
this.tpl is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

html:this.tpl.apply(planetEarth)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that is not how JavaScript scoping works...

In your example there are 2 ways to do what you would want to do:

```
//this is the bad way imo, since its not really properly scoped.
// you are declaring the planeEarth and tpl globally
// ( or wherever the scope of your define is. )
var plantetEarth = { name: "Earth", mass: 1.00 }
var tpl = new Ext.Template(['<tpl for".">', '<p> {name} </p>', '</tpl>'].join(''));
tpl.compile();
Ext.define('casta.view.Intro', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    //alias: 'widget.currentDate', //this makes it xtype 'currentDate'
    //store: 'CurrentDateStore',


    initComponent: function(){

        this.callParent(arguments);

    },
    html:tpl.apply(planetEarth)
});
```

or

```
//I would do some variation of this personally.
//It's nice and neat, everything is scoped properly, etc etc
Ext.define('casta.view.Intro', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    //alias: 'widget.currentDate', //this makes it xtype 'currentDate'
    //store: 'CurrentDateStore',


    initComponent: function(){

        this.tpl = new Ext.Template(['<tpl for".">', '<p> {name} </p>', '</tpl>'].join(''));
        this.tpl.compile();
        this.tpl.apply(this.planetEarth);
        this.html = this.tpl.apply(this.planetEarth)
        this.callParent(arguments);

    },

});
```